# How to match words as if in a dictionary, based on len-1 or len+1? Python

Tags: python, list, comparison

If I have a word 'raqd', how would I use python to have a spellcheck, so to speak, to find the word 'rad' as an option in 'spellcheck'? What I've been trying to do is this:

```
def isbettermatch(keysplit, searchword):
    i = 0
    trues = 0
    falses = 0

    lensearchwords = len(searchword)

    keysplits = copy.deepcopy(keysplit)
    searchwords = copy.deepcopy(searchword)
    #print keysplit, searchwords
    if len(keysplits)  == len(searchwords)-1:
        i = 0
        while i < len(keysplits):
            j = 0
            while j < lensearchwords:
                if keysplits[i] == searchwords[j]:
                    trues +=1
                    searchwords.pop(j)
                    lensearchwords = len(searchwords)
                elif keysplits[i] != searchwords[j]:
                    falses +=1
                j +=1
            i +=1
        if trues >= len(searchwords)-1:
            #print "-------------------------------------------------------", keysplits
            return True
```

`keysplit` is a list like `['s', 'p', 'o', 'i', 'l']` for example, and the `searchword` would be a list `['r', 'a', 'q', 'd']`.

If the function returns `True`, then it would print the keyword that matches. Ex. 'rad', for the `searchword` 'raqd'.

I need to find all possible matches for the `searchword` with a single letter addition or deletion.

so ex. 'raqd' would have an option to be 'rad', and 'poted' could be 'posted' or 'potted'.

So far I've been trying to compare the characters in each word against each other using lists. My question is: why is my current strategy not working, and how can I improve it? I'm not sure why it is giving me incorrect output:

```
dna   ira   fra   had   har   nra   jar   jaq   bra   era   amd
```

is just a small example of the words I'm getting

Comment: Check this out: http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html

Comment: @SnakesandCoffee, I would like to base it more off of the code I have so far written. I did see that example before when I was researching my problem but I think I'd have to destroy everything I've written so far

Comment: What's the basis of your approach? And what is your question?

Comment: There's no reason that you can't read the theory in Norvig's post and implement it yourself, without copying his code

Answer (score 2):

I had to write a spellchecker once for a course assignment long ago. It pretty much had to do what you were saying: Given a 'word', suggest all the possible matches given a single letter addition or deletion. What I recall doing was load the main dictionary word list into a hash table (something with quick O(1) access), then for the given word, generate all the possible combinations with letter additions and deletions and check if they were in the main word list. Any matches would be used as a suggestion.

For a more complex spell checker, you could try writing a BK-Tree with Levenshtein Distance:
http://blog.notdot.net/2007/4/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Part-1-BK-Trees

Comment: how does one use a hash table? Sorry, I am a beginner

Comment: @pearbear: In Python dictionaries are equivalent to hash tables.

Comment: Using a Python dict in this way is now done using sets. Keeps you from creating a false "mapping" with all values of 0 or None, just to get fast checking for existence in the key space. value in set() is how this is done in current Python versions (since about v2.4).